# Hyperparameter Tuning in Random Forest Model

Tags: machine-learning, python, predictive-modeling, hyperparameter-tuning

I'm new to the machine learning field, and I'm learning ML models by practice, and I'm facing an issue while using the machine learning model.

While I'm implementing the `RandomForestClassifier model` with hyper tunning it's taking too much time to predict output. And I'm also using `GridSearchCV` on it. so it's take much time.

Is there any way how can I solve this problem.

OR, Is `Google Colab` or `Kaggle Notebook` editor can perform better than `Jupiter Notebook` ?

Comment: Are you training with a GPU? If no then it definitely will be slow. Yes GridSearchCV is very slow when it comes to hyperparameter optimization even when training with a GPU. You could use RandomSearchCV which is faster but the best option would be to use a Bayesian Optimizer. A library I would recommend for this is Hyperopt.

Comment: Okay, My computer doesn't have any GPU, so is there any way to run it on Google Colab or Kaggle Kernal? Or it provides GPU facility.

Comment: I will add an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the GPU by going to the settings:

```
Runtime> Change runtime type and select GPU as Hardware accelerator.
```